# NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays. Angular error, unable to use GET API for front end HTML

Tags: angular, httpclient, angular-httpclient

My component.ts file

```js
export class TeamComponent implements OnInit {

    teams: any;

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        let resp = this.http.get("https://api.squiggle.com.au/?q=teams");
        resp.subscribe((data) => this.teams = data);
    }
}
```

My HTML File

```html
<section class="teams container text-center">
    <h1>List of Teams</h1>
        <table class="table table-dark">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">ID</th>
                <th scope="col">Abbrev</th>
                <th scope="col">Logo</th>
                <th scope="col">Team Name</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let team of teams">
                <td>{{team.id}}</td>
                <td>{{team.abbrev}}</td>
                <td>{{team.logo}}</td>
                <td>{{team.name}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</section>
```

I am able to console log my team data through HTTP Client but when i try to display it on HTML by declaring team: any; Console is throwing error 
"Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays."

Comment: Try replacing `resp.subscribe((data) => this.teams = data);` with `resp.pipe(map(r => r['teams']).subscribe((data) => this.teams = data);`. The array is contained in the property `teams`. Also assign empty array at definition: `teams = [];`.

Comment: property 'subscribe' does not exist in type 'OperatorFunction'. Also what is r suppose to stand for? thanks

Comment: I missed a close parenthesis: `resp.pipe(map(r => r['teams'])).subscribe((data) => this.teams = data)`. Notice two closing brackets before subscribe.

Comment: works perfect! thanks for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following,

```
this.httpClient.get("https://api.squiggle.com.au/?q=teams").subscribe((res: any) => {
         this.responseData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(res))["teams"];
        },
        err => {
          console.log(err);
        },
        () => {
          console.log(this.responseData);
         }
       )
      }
```

You should be able to iterate the responseData using *ngFor directive now.

Also, you can declare responseData as `responseData: any`

Comment: works great, any tutorial related to this that may help me?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to iterate over `teams: any` which is not initialized. You can change the declaration of `teams`, it should fix it :

```js
teams: any[] = [];
```

---

Also, the root content returned from the API is an `object`, not an `array` :

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
    let resp = this.http.get("https://api.squiggle.com.au/?q=teams");
    resp.subscribe((data) => this.teams = data.teams); // here, you need to set this.teams from data.teams
}
```

Comment: now its a different error, Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed.

Comment: what's the content of `data` returned from the API ?

Comment: it returns an object, not an array. I'll edit my post

Comment: "Property 'teams' does not exist on type Object" after using data.teams. I have changed the declaration of teams aswell

Answer (score 1):

yes declaration part declare this like

```
teams;
```

Answer (score 1):

That error makes me think that you are trying to iterate over an object.

Try using `keyvalue` pipe like so:

```
<tr *ngFor="let team of teams | keyvalue">
```

Answer (score -1):

In your response you are getting teams object as array of objects (`{teams: Array(18)}`), so you have to assign `this.teamsData = data.teams`.

Comment: so what would teamsData, and teams be declared as ?

Comment: teamsData: any;

getTeamsData() {
      this.assetService.getTeamsData().subscribe(res => {
        this.teamsData = res.teams;
        console.log(res);
      });
    }

Comment: and your response is in this format  right : {teams: Array(18)} , so res.teams you should assign to teamsData